# How to protect yourself from a Vulcan nerve pinch?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

Is there any way for a human to protect themself from the dreaded Vulcan nerve pinch?  Apparently the only humans to remain conscious through a Vulcan nerve pinch are those who have been genetically altered.  Could just wearing a neckguard help perhaps?

Comment: Become genetically altered? </joke>

Comment: My hypothesis is that if a Vulcan can't get to your neck, they can probably do the telepathic rendering somewhere else on your body.  Might need to find some way to block the Vulcan telepathy maybe.  Are there any recorded instances of the Vulcan nerve pinch not being performed on the neck?

Comment: This is completely cross-universe, but Stargate Command was able to block telekinesis by generating certain sounds to impair the brain regions associated with telekinesis.  A similar technique using sound was also done in /Warehouse 13/.

Comment: Being completely non-fictional helps a great deal. ;)

Comment: Have you tried: "*Please, please, pleasepleaseplease don't Vulcan Nerve Pinch Me!  I'll be good, I promise!*"?

Comment: shoot the vulcan first.

Comment: Wear a neckguard?

Comment: Get a surgeon to move it. Perhaps due to a wartime injury...

Comment: … *mumble mumble **Serenity** mumble* …

Comment: Pretty sure it's called a neck pinch, not nerve pinch.

Comment: @FuxieDK, I thought that too!  But "nerve pinch" is the term used on Wikipedia.  That is why I was wondering if it can be applied to places other than the neck.

Comment: @Nicole Sharp, Lately I have been re-watching ST:ENT and ST:VOY, and unless they mumble, they say neck, not nerve..

Comment: The Serenity poke was funny.

Comment: Be extremely polite to Vulcans

Answer (score 2):

The nerve pinch is, and I don't know if this is purely accidental, close to the sinoatrial node in the neck that regulates the blood flow to the brain. From my experience in martial arts, I am aware that hitting the correct point can immobilize an opponent. A vulcan nerve pinch is IMHO (and I am have no degree in medicine, biology or anything similar) simply a more sophisticated version of hitting that nerve. So, I'd say, there is no biological defence against and you'd need an armour (e.g. a medival neck plate) to protect from it.

I am also not aware of any nerve pinch being executed somewhere else than the neck.

Comment: Or you could belong to a species whose physiology doesn't put a nerve there.