# How do you protect yourself from the Doctor's Venusian aikido?

Tags: doctor-who

Related: [How to protect yourself from a Vulcan nerve pinch?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183389/how-to-protect-yourself-from-a-vulcan-nerve-pinch) But about *Doctor Who* instead of *Star Trek*.

See the below examples of the Doctor doing Venusian aikido, from top to bottom, left to right: Third Doctor doing Venusian aikido, Thirteenth Doctor about to do Venusian aikido on a guy and Twelfth Doctor uses Venusian aikido to dodge its highly effective.

[image: Third Doctor example] [image: Thirteenth Doctor example]

[image: Twelfth Doctor example]

How do you protect yourself from the Doctor's Venusian aikido? Is it even possible to defend yourself from Venusian aikido?

Comment: 1) Presumably by being a much greater expert in Venusian aikido or some other martial art so you can block the Doctor's attacks and attack him with attacks he can't block.  2) By being surrounded by robot bodyguards.  3) By drawing your ray gun and blasting him first.  4) By being as big and strong as an elephant or a whale. 5) By never being on the same planet as the Doctor. 6) By always being on the Doctor's side.  Etc., etc., etc.,

Comment: It's ineffective against Sontarans; https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Venusian_aikido

Answer (score 1):

As [Valorum has pointed out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220596/how-do-you-protect-yourself-from-the-doctors-venusian-aikido#comment602391_220596) by simply being a Sontaran you can not be attacked by Venusian aikido

And as [M. A. Golding has said](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220596/how-do-you-protect-yourself-from-the-doctors-venusian-aikido#comment602381_220596):

> 1) Presumably by being a much greater expert in Venusian aikido or some other martial art so you can block the Doctor's attacks and attack him with attacks he can't block. 2) By being surrounded by robot bodyguards. 3) By drawing your ray gun and blasting him first. 4) By being as big and strong as an elephant or a whale. 5) By never being on the same planet as the Doctor. 6) By always being on the Doctor's side. Etc., etc., etc.,

So there are various ways to stop Venusian aikido simply because it, like any martial art, has periods where you are left open to attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Venusian Akido includes moves such as joint locks, throws and kicks, but you seem to be referring specifically to the move to immobilise an opponent.

This move appears to work by using *pressure points*. In the Third Doctor story *Inferno*, The Doctor is seen to jab his thumb in the region of Stahlman's collar bone:

> BRIGADIER: Doctor! What on earth do you think you're doing?
>   DOCTOR: Venusian karate. It's very effective. Hold it long enough and the subject remains permanently paralysed.

The simple answer to your question of how to protect yourself from such a move must be *to protect your pressure points*. This would suggest that you would have to be aware of the art in order to know where you should protect. Of course, in all combat, defence is important, and presumably if two persons fluent in Venusian Akido were to fight each other, there would be a victor.